# Ubuntu Server 21.04 Download Speed Very Slow on a Lenovo Ideapad 300S with Realtek Driver R8169

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo, ethernet

Thanks in advance for reading my issue!

Running Ubuntu Server 21.04 (kernel 5.11.0-34-generic) and have run into a serious network issue where the internet download speed is around 25Mbps on a 150Mbps connection!

My setup:

- Lenovo Ideapad 300S with a wired Ethernet connection.
- Running Ubuntu Server 21.04 (kernel version 5.11.0-34-generic).
- Wired Ethernet connection with RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (r8169) driver.
- My contract with the ISP is for a 150Mbps download speed.

My problem:

The download speed is extremely low, around 25Mbps whereas my upload speed is 'normal' around 80-90Mbps. I use 'speedtest-cli' for measuring the bandwidth, by the way.

This problem does not happen on an Acer Aspire One laptop running the same kernel and connected to the same router.

I do see some rx_missed in the 'ethtool' output, not sure if this is symptomatic of a problem with the r8169 driver.

I searched through many articles that talked about the r8169 driver having problems but they were all on older kernel versions. I'm not even sure if that's the issue here.

```
ethtool -S enp3s0
NIC statistics:
     tx_packets: 320715
     rx_packets: 203088
     tx_errors: 0
     rx_errors: 0
     rx_missed: 2497
     align_errors: 0
     tx_single_collisions: 0
     tx_multi_collisions: 0
     unicast: 202217
     broadcast: 63
     multicast: 808
     tx_aborted: 0
     tx_underrun: 0
```

Output from lspci -vnvn -s 03:00.0:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
        Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3835]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
        Region 0: I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Region 2: Memory at d1204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Region 4: Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
                        ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
                        ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
                         10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Via message/WAKE#, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR+ OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
                PBA: BAR=4 offset=00000800
        Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
                        MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
                HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
        Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [170 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
                Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
                Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Capabilities: [178 v1] L1 PM Substates
                L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
                          PortCommonModeRestoreTime=150us PortTPowerOnTime=150us
                L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1-
                           T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=294912ns
                L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=150us
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Thanks,
PE

Comment: I've already tried the "pci=nomsi" kernel option and it doesn't address the problem.

Comment: The other weird thing is, I completely disabled the wired Ethernet interface and brought it up on just the wifi interface and the speeds were just as bad. To me that rules out the r8169 driver as the potential issue here. I really appreciate any suggestion on what to do next.